# how to prove a multivariable function can be written as production of seperate single variable function?

Tags: functions

$$f(x,y,z) = e^{-xy-yz-zx}$$
How to prove that there exist no function $g_1(x),g_2(y),g_3(z)$, such that:
$$f(x,y,z) = g_1(x)g_2(y)g_3(z)$$

More generally, is there theorem/concept about this topic, about the sufficient condition that $f(x,y,z)$ can't be expressed as $g_1(x)g_2(y)g_3(z)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x,y,z)$ be given by
$$f(x,y,z) = e^{-xy-yz-zx}$$
and suppose there are functions $g_1,g_2,g_3$ such that
$$f(x,y,z) = g_1(x)g_2(y)g_3(z)$$
Since $f$ is always nonzero, $g_1,g_2,g_3$ are also always nonzero.
Then for all $x$
$$1 = f(x,0,0) = g_1(x)g_2(0)g_3(0) = cg_1(x)$$
where $c = g_2(0)g_3(0)$.

It folllows that $g_1$ is a constant function.

Similarly, the functions $g_2,\,g_3$ are constant.

But $f$ is not constant, so we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:  Suppose functions $g_1(x)$, $g_2(y)$, $g_3(z)$ exist such that $f(x,y,z) = g_1(x) g_2(y) g_3(z)$.  WLOG, we can take all three $g_i$ functions are strictly positive as well (why?).  Now consider the function $h(x,y,z) = \ln f(x,y,z)$.  What must be true about the partial derivatives of this function with respect to $x$, $y$, and $z$?

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x,y,z) = g_1(x)g_2(y)g_3(z)$ then since $f(x,y,z) \neq 0,$
we must have $g_1(x) \neq 0,$ $g_2(y) \neq 0,$ and $g_3(z) \neq 0,$ so
$$
\frac{f(0,0,1)}{f(0,0,0)} = \frac{g_1(0)g_2(0)g_3(1)}{g_1(0)g_2(0)g_3(0)}
 = \frac{g_3(1)}{g_3(0)}
 = \frac{g_1(0)g_2(1)g_3(1)}{g_1(0)g_2(1)g_3(0)}
 = \frac{f(0,1,1)}{f(0,1,0)}.
$$

Or in short,
$$
\frac{f(0,0,1)}{f(0,0,0)} 
 = \frac{f(0,1,1)}{f(0,1,0)}.
$$

From the definition already given for $f,$ you can evaluate both
sides of this equation. Is the equation true?